# java.sql.Driver stub not being recognized by java.sql.DriverManger

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, jdbc

I am trying to unit test a thin data access layer that I've written. I was hoping I wouldn't have to inject a stub of DriverManager into the class that makes the connection, and I don't have a mock framework available. I have check my implementation against [MockRunner's MockDriver](http://mockrunner.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mockrunner/mockrunner/src/com/mockrunner/mock/jdbc/MockDriver.java?revision=1.1&view=markup) and it is very similar, but when I run the test I get a SQLException: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306." Here is the stub code:

```
public class DriverStub implements Driver
{
    @Override
    public boolean acceptsURL(String URL) throws SQLException
    {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException
    {
        return new ConnectionStub();
    }
    @Override
    public int getMajorVersion()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public int getMinorVersion()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public DriverPropertyInfo[] getPropertyInfo(String url, Properties info)
    throws SQLException
    {
        return new DriverPropertyInfo[0];
    }
    @Override
    public boolean jdbcCompliant()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

A fragment of the calling code:

```
Connection connection = null;
try
{
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
}
...
try
{
    connection = Drivermanager.getConnection(...);
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Driver` implementation should register an instance of the `Driver` through [DriverManager.registerDriver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver%28java.sql.Driver%29) in its static initialiser.

```
public class DriverStub implements Driver {
    static {
        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new DriverStub());
    }
    ...
}
```

It's a complete and utter hack, but there you go. Personally, I'd suggest ignoring `DriverManager` and linking directly to the driver.

Comment: Thank you. I'm quite comfortable using a hack in testing as long as it's not a gross hack and not one that results in integration testing. How do you link directly to the driver and does that have an advantage for the production code?

Comment: In the end I've put the manual registering code in a @BeforeClass method on the unit test in question; at that point, I don't see it as any more of a hack than any of the other fake things you have to do to unit test.

Comment: @Kazark A trouble using the DriverManager static method is that the driver remains registered. Another test with another driver (accepting the same URLs) may have problems.

Comment: Okay, thanks; good to know. I suppose I could use `deregisterDriver` in a teardown if that became a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be far more effort than it's worth.  Why would you want to stub the DriverManager?  What does that test?  How do you prove the worth of your data access layer by not using a real driver manager?  Don't you want to connect to a database to test?

I'd load the JDBC driver and be done with it.  This seems like mocking run amok to me.

Comment: You are right of course that an (_integration_) test with the database is important. However, I would need to hear a more extensive argument to convince me that unit testing isn't worth it in this case. For example, it could be helpful to isolate where the problem is if the integration tests are failing.

Comment: Also, the effort required is not very high with Tom Hawtin's answer.